# Python - Pandas - drop specific columns (axis)?

Tags: python, pandas, spreadsheet, axis, drop

So I got a numeric list `[0-12]` that matches the length of my columns in my spreadsheet and also replaced the column headers with that list `df.columns = list`.
Now i want to drop specific columns out of that spreadsheet like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Tt9.png).

To create the list of numbers to match the length of columns I got this:

```
listOfNumbers = []

column_name = []
for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    listOfNumbers.append(i)

df.columns = listOfNumbers

for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(1, len(df.columns)):
        if i != colList[j]:
            df.drop(i, inplace=True)
```

And I got the list `[1,2,3]` as seen in the picture.
But i always get this Error:

> KeyError: '[1] not found in axis

I tried to replace `df.drop(i, inplace=True)` with `df.drop(i, axis=1, inplace=True)` but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the proper way will be:

```
columns_to_remove = [1, 2, 3] # columns to delete
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[columns_to_remove])
```

So for your use case:

```
for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(1, len(df.columns)):
        if i != colList[j]:
            df.drop(columns=df.columns[i], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop every column that **does not appear** in `colList`, this code does it, using set difference:

```
setOfNumbers = set(range(df.shape[1]))
setRemainColumns = set(colList)
for dropColumn in setOfNumbers.difference(setRemainColumns):
     df.drop(dropColumn, axis=1, inplace=True)
```